# Refresh/Reload fragment when there is a database delete

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a simple app with fragment and activity hosting a RecyclerView, with data from a database, i have a delete function in my adapter, the contents gets deleted from the database, but the View is not getting refreshed. I have tried a few answers for similar questions asked, but couldn't fix them. Please find the code snippets for my fragment and adapter.

Fragment Code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_medication, container, false);
    medicationsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    String userId = sharedPreferences.getString(Preferences.USERID,null);
    if (userId != null) {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId).child("medications");
    }
    toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.medication));
    addMedButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.addMedicationButton);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.medications_recycler);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Medication medication = snapshot.getValue(Medication.class);
                String medicationKey = snapshot.getKey();
                medication.setKey(medicationKey);
                medicationsArrayList.add(medication);
            }
            mAdapter = new MedicationsAdapter(getContext(), medicationsArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            registerForContextMenu(recyclerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Adapter:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.medications_adapter, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Medication medication = mMedicationList.get(position);
    holder.dateMed.setText(medication.getDateMed());
    holder.medicationName.setText(medication.getMedicationName());
    holder.dosage.setText(medication.getDosage() + " " + mContext.getString(R.string.dosageUnit));
    holder.initialTime.setText(medication.getInitialTime());
    holder.startDate.setText(medication.getStartDate());
    holder.endDate.setText(medication.getEndDate());
    holder.frequency.setText(medication.getFrequency());
    holder.medication_key.setText(medication.getKey());
    holder.reason.setText(medication.getReason());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mMedicationList == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return mMedicationList.size();
    }
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
    TextView dateMed, medicationName, dosage, initialTime, startDate, endDate, frequency, reason, medication_key;


    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        dateMed = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateMedAdd);
        medicationName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.medicationName);
        dosage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dosage);
        initialTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.initialTime);
        startDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.startDate);
        endDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.endDate);
        frequency = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.frequency);
        reason = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reason);
        medication_key = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.medication_key);

    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Medications Options");
        MenuItem editMed = menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");//groupId, itemId, order, title
        MenuItem deleteMed = menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
        editMed.setOnMenuItemClickListener(medicationsMenuClicked);
        deleteMed.setOnMenuItemClickListener(medicationsMenuClicked);
    }

    private void deleteVitalsByKey(String key) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference;
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("medications").child(key);
        databaseReference.removeValue();

    }

    private final MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener medicationsMenuClicked = new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            View v = item.getActionView();
            if (item.getTitle() == "Edit") {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Redirecting to edit screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent editMedIntent = new Intent(mContext, MedicationActivity.class);
                editMedIntent.putExtra("medications_key", medication_key.getText());
                mContext.startActivity(editMedIntent);
                return true;
            } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                deleteVitalsByKey(medication_key.getText().toString());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Want to refresh the fragment UI to reflect the change of the delete. Kindly help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do same thing after you delete an item from recyclerview list.
That is when you click delete then invoke a function where you first delete an item then update the database then get back all the data then clean you recycler view then again add it fresh.

```
 DatabasePayShare db= new DatabasePayShare(getContext());
        folderDatas= db.GetAllFolder();
        FolderAdapter folderAdapter= new FolderAdapter(getActivity(), folderDatas);
        folListView.setAdapter(folderAdapter);
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatabasePayShare db= new DatabasePayShare(getContext());
                FolderData folderData= new FolderData(0,"Folder "+(folListView.getCount()+1), getDate());
                long rowId= db.AddNewFolderToLocalDatabase(folderData);

                db= new DatabasePayShare(getContext());
                final ArrayList<FolderData> folderDatas= db.GetAllFolder();
                FolderAdapter folderAdapter= new FolderAdapter(getActivity(), folderDatas);
                folListView.setAdapter(folderAdapter);

            }
        });
```

Check this piece of code where i have one list view which contains an image and two textview. On clicking an item over it I wanted to add one more list item. SO i added the tuple in database. After adding i again called database filled up the list again.
I did it in listview you can check it in yours.

Comment: Agarwal: Could you please elaborate on that?. I create a contextMenu, where I call this function on delete deleteVitalsByKey(medication_key.getText().toString());
This function removes the ID from the database. How do you refresh the recycler view?